# When did Google Search start sending X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN?

Tags: iframe, http-headers

I've got an automated test for our application that includes displaying a Google search box in an IFrame.  The test started failing recently, when a developer checked in a change that broke several other tests.  I'm starting to doubt that the change broke this test, but I'd love to know for sure.  As of right now, I can see that Google search (*i.e.*, http://www.google.com/search?q=whatever) returns an `X-Frame-Options` header with `SAMEORIGIN`, which tells the browser not to display the search page in our IFrame.  Which is Google's right to insist on, and I don't mind that.  But to help me figure out if the test failure is the fault of the developer's code change or simply a coincidence, I'd love to know **when did Google start sending this X-Frame-Options header?**  If it happens to be around the right time, we'll just change the test to do something more appropriate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This article](http://blog.futtta.be/2009/12/02/google-inadvertently-killing-talk-badges-with-x-frame-options/) explains how it broke some chat software in December 2009. So it's been at least two years.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that one (I did a fair amount of hunting before asking this question).  But that's Google Chat, which is a completely different animal.  Some folks are reporting recent (*e.g.*, last 10 days) changes to Google Maps to add the header, but again, that's not Search.  But thanks for the answer - I anticipated a lot of "you dumb n00b" answers and hesitated to post this :-)

Comment: It's possible that they rolled this out at different times for different services. Since no one seems to have commented yet on Google's search product it may be a very new thing. If you blog about it you can be the first to report and maybe get a good amount of traffic to your site. :)