# Submitting a HTML form to go to a URL does not load the webpage? It starts to load then nothing happens?

Tags: html

here is my HTML form:

```
 <form action="http://www.google.com/search" method="get">
   <input type="text" name="q">
   <input type="submit">
 </form>
```

I test the form with online HTML editors like the one here: http://www.htmlinstant.com/
When I click submit it very quickly says "Waiting for google.com" down the bottom of the page, then it says "Connecting...", then nothing happens. It stays on the page with the form.

I tried searching for a solution to the problem by searching "HTML form not loading page" and similar things. But there doesn't seem to be anything relevant. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is refused by Google because it expects the form post request to originate from the same server (ie: google.com). You can 'disable X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN' option only if you're the site owner. You might want to consider looking into their API's.

Here's another thread I found on that issue: [When did Google Search start sending X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905169/when-did-google-search-start-sending-x-frame-options-sameorigin)